# I am getting an error of Broadcast receiver as a null point exception in Android studio. I want to receive GCM notifications

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM to get notifications on my app. For that I am generating the registration id on sign in and sign up. After the sign in or sign up process it throws and error of null point exception for onRecieve method.

This error occurs sometimes and sometimes it doesn't occurs.

Here is the logcat of the error.

```
01-15 12:26:02.935 22448-22448/com.simpler W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
01-15 12:26:02.936 22448-22448/com.simpler W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
01-15 12:26:02.936 22448-22448/com.simpler W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
01-15 12:26:02.936 22448-22448/com.simpler W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
01-15 12:26:02.936 22448-22448/com.simpler W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
01-15 12:26:02.936 22448-22448/com.simpler W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
01-15 12:26:02.936 22448-22448/com.simpler W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5649)
01-15 12:26:02.936 22448-22448/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-15 12:26:02.936 22448-22448/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-15 12:26:02.936 22448-22448/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
01-15 12:26:02.936 22448-22448/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Here is the code to generate token on Sign in:

```
private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
private static final String TAG1 = "SignInActivity";
private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;

mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                    boolean sentToken = sharedPreferences
                            .getBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);
                    if (sentToken) {
                        System.out.println(getString(R.string.gcm_send_message));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(getString(R.string.token_error_message));
                    }
                }
            };
if (checkPlayServices()) 
{
    // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
    Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
    startService(intent);
}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG1, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you using `mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver` to receive the GCM push notification? You can refer to this article (http://www.zionsoft.net/2014/02/google-play-services-push-notification-cloud-messaging/) as a tutorial.

Comment: Two things: 1.) I hope you have already added Register in AndroidManifest of your app.
2.) Why you are declaring one PRIVATE Instance variable first for your register and then creating an anonymous inner class for it. You should declare a simple public inner class for it.

Comment: you will also need to share with us the line you are seeing the error on so we can assist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your localbroadcastmanger in the code

```
if (checkPlayServices()) {
// Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
startService(intent);

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(SignInActivity.this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("reg complete string"));

}
```